# Multi-part form file Upload - AWS Gateway

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I've create a .net Web API deploy on AWS.

The API is accessible through the AWS API Gateway. I know that the aws gateway was not supporting multi-part form so I'm wondering if it is still the case.
I have added the endpoint on the AWS gateway as pass-though and binary contact but the file gets lost.

Comment: yes aws api gateway supports multipart data now if you need further help let me know

Comment: can you please point me to any link ? I can call the endpoint using the gateway link but it looks like that "the web api code" won't get any file (in fact is through an exception)

Comment: where are you parsing the files in aws lambda ?

Comment: there is not lamda.   AWS gateway --> File Upload Endpoint (.net web api).
The file is parsed in the .net code using the httpRequest.Files method.

Comment: see aws api gateway does not natively support multipart uploads, what type of files you are going to upload ?

Comment: size and type of files ?

Comment: .jpg and .pdf.  Max size 3MB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180354/discussion-between-massimiliano-peluso-and-varnit).

Comment: see why don't you use aws lambda first and then upload it to s3 and then fetch it from your .net app, i know its kinda cumbersome to handle but we are very limited with options here